# implementing mask-r-cnn with tensorflow-distributed

Tags: python, linux, tensorflow, faster-rcnn, distributed-tensorflow

I'm training a [mask-r-cnn network](https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN), which is built on tensorflow and keras. I'm searching for a way to reduce training time, so I thought implementing it with tensorflow-distributed.

I've been working with mask-r-cnn for some time, but it seems what I'm trying to do will require me to modify the source code of mask-r-cnn, which is above my current skills.

So, my question is, has someone ever done it, or something similar? is it possible at all, or am I misunderstand the use of tensorflow-distributed.

Thanks ahead.

Answer (score 0):

Even without distributed training, the tensorpack implementation of Mask R-CNN in tensorflow [runs 5x faster](https://github.com/tensorpack/benchmarks/tree/master/MaskRCNN) (and more accurate as well) than the one you linked to.

It also supports distributed training with MPI.